# Problema al modificar datos en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Realize el siguiente código para actualizar, me imprime         "datos actualizados" pero al momento de revisar en la base  de datos no se modifica, ayuda

```
 If(isset($_POST[btn_actualizar]))
{
    $Id = $_POST['Id'] ;
    $codigo_producto = $_POST['codigo_producto'] ;
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'] ;
    $precio_unitario =$_POST['precio_unitario'] ;
    $valor_total = $cantidad * $precio_unitario;

    If ($Id =="" || $codigo_producto =="" ||            $cantidad=="" || $precio_unitario =="") {
    Echo "llenar todos los campo" ;
    }
Else
    {
    $_UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE compras set
    Id = '$Id' ;
    codigo_producto = '$codigo_producto' ;
    cantidad = '$cantidad' ;
    precio_unitario = '$precio_unitario' ;
    valor_total = '$cantidad'  * '$precio_unitario';

    where Id = '$Id' ;
    mysqli_query($conexión, $UPDATE_SQL) ;
    echo "datos actualizados";
    } 
    }
```

Comment: probaste en tu consulta poner las variables sin comillas simples?  y por otro lado, hacer la operación ``$cantidad * $precio_unitario`` fuera de la consulta y pasar el resultado?

Comment: Consejo no capitalices la letra inicial del if o else así no van

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis en la consulta `$_UPDATE_SQL`, pues no cierras la variable con comillas al final, no sé si el error fue al transcribir el código aquí. Otra cosa es que generalmente el `Id` nunca se actualiza en las tablas. Como ya indica @Mani, conviene que hagas el cálculo fuera de la consulta.

Comment: No me habia fijado en la comillas que me faltaba muchas gracias amigo y como podría calcular la operación fuera de la consulta?

Comment: No sabía lo de que if y else no iban con mayúsculas ya lo verifico muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en tu código. Los he ido poniendo en los mismos comentarios de la solución que te propongo.

He mejorado varias cosas, todas están en comentarios. He estandarizado el código. Generalmente en PHP los elementos del lenguaje tales como `echo, if, else...` se escriben en minúscula.

Aquí va el código. Si lo haces así debería funcionar. Si no funciona o no entiendes algo puedes decirlo en comentarios.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_actualizar']))
{
    /*
        Usaremos ternarios para verificar si los datos del POST se llenaron
        del paso los guardaremos en variables y en lo adelante usaremos las variables
        esta práctica ayuda a clarificar un poco el código
    */
    $Id = ( !empty($_POST['Id']) ) ?  $_POST['Id'] : NULL;
    $codigo = ( !empty($_POST['codigo_producto']) ) ?  $_POST['codigo_producto'] : NULL;
    $cantidad = ( !empty($_POST['cantidad']) ) ?  $_POST['cantidad'] : NULL;
    $precio = ( !empty($_POST['precio_unitario']) ) ?  $_POST['precio_unitario'] : NULL;
    $total = $cantidad * $precio;

    /*
        El criterio natural sería: si hay datos en las variables, lanzar el UPDATE
        Creo que estabas siguiendo una lógica inversa
    */
    if ( $Id && $codigo && $cantidad && $precio ) 
    {
        /*
            Aquí habría varios errores de sintaxis
            1. No cerrabas la variable con comillas (")
            2. Habría varios puntos y coma
            También en consultas UPDATE no se suele modificar el Id
            Lo he quitado de los set, si hay que modificarlo lo pones
        */
        $sql = "UPDATE compras set
        codigo_producto = '$codigo' 
        cantidad = '$cantidad' 
        precio_unitario = '$precio' 
        valor_total = '$total'
        where Id = '$Id' ";
        /*
            Verificamos si no hay error en la consulta
            en un UPDATE puede ocurrir error de clave duplicada u otro
            ADVERTENCIA IMPORTANTE: Evita usar variables acentuadas, como $conexión
        */
        if ( $stmt=mysqli_query($conexión, $sql) ) 
        { 
            /*Imprimimos cuántas filas se actualizaron*/
            $msg=printf ("Se actualizaron %d filas",mysqli_affected_rows($conexión)); #Evita usar variables con acento
        }
        else
        {
            /*Imprimimos si hubo error en la consulta*/
            $msg="Hubo un error en la consulta";            
        } 
    }
    else
    { 
        $msg="llenar todos los campos" ;
    }
}
else
{
    $msg="No se pulsó en botón actualizar";     
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: ! Empty para que me funciona amigo?

Comment: @BenjaVicos `!empty(...)` con el signo `!` delante es como si preguntaras: ¿no está vacío? El ternario lo que hace es: si la condición es verdadera, asigna lo que hay después de  `?` si es falsa asigna lo que hay después de `:`. Es como un `if` abreviado. Aquí por ejemplo: `$Id = ( !empty($_POST['Id']) ) ?  $_POST['Id'] : NULL;` significa: *«Si `$_POST['Id']` no está vacío, asigna a la variable `$Id` lo que haya en `$_POST['Id']`, de lo contrario asigna a `$Id` el valor `NULL`»*.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un problema en tu query.

```
$_UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE compras set
Id = '$Id' ;
codigo_producto = '$codigo_producto' ;
cantidad = '$cantidad' ;
precio_unitario = '$precio_unitario' ;
valor_total = '$cantidad'  * '$precio_unitario';

where Id = '$Id' ;
```

; indica que aquí se termina el string del query intenta de la siguiente manera

```
$_UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE compras SET
Id = '$Id',
codigo_producto = '$codigo_producto',
cantidad = '$cantidad',
precio_unitario = '$precio_unitario',
valor_total = '$cantidad*$precio_unitario'
WHERE Id = '$Id';
```